# How to save data from Json with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to save "author" data to global variable named "authors" from json(Link:"https://learnappmaking.com/ex/books.json") with these two libraries. But it only works at the trailing closure of `func Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON`. When I access the global variable named "authors" from somewhere except the trailing closure, what I get is an empty array of string.

Can someone explain the reason behind this werid situation？
Thanks a lot.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var authors = [String]()
    let url = "https://learnappmaking.com/ex/books.json"


    func getAuthorsCount() {
        print("the number of authors : \(authors.count)") // I hope that here, the number of authors should be 3 too! actually, it is 0. Why? 

        // this for loop doesn't get excuted
        for author in authors {
            print(author)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
                    for item in json["books"].arrayValue {
                        var outputString: String
                        print(item["author"])
                        outputString = item["author"].stringValue
                        //urlOfProjectAsset.append(outputString)
                        self.authors.append(outputString)
                        print("authors.count: \(self.authors.count)")
                    }
                }
            }
    }

        getAuthorsCount()
        print("-------------")
    }
}
```

the actual output is:

[image]

---

**Update**：
I adjusted my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var authors = [String]()
    let url = "https://learnappmaking.com/ex/books.json"


    func getAuthorsCount() {
        print("the number of authors : \(authors.count)")

        // this for loop doesn't get excuted
        for author in authors {
            print(author)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
                    for item in json["books"].arrayValue {
                        var outputString: String
                        //print(item["author"])
                        outputString = item["author"].stringValue
                        //urlOfProjectAsset.append(outputString)
                        self.authors.append(outputString)
                        //print("authors.count: \(self.authors.count)")
                    }
                self.getAuthorsCount() // I added this line of code.
                }
            }
    }
        getAuthorsCount()
        print("-------------")
    }
}
```

But why does the `func getAuthorsCount()` (not self. version) still print an empty array of strings ? I think the result should be the same as the result which 
`func self.getAuthorsCount()` printed.
I am so confused now...
Again, I want to use the data kept in the variable named "authors", but  what I only got is an empty array of strings.

Comment: Make sure you are accessing the getAuthorsCount after you are getting the result. It's not clear from your example

Comment: You are calling the `getAuthorsCount()` before the request returns from the server. Move it inside the callback, after the `for` statement and it will work.

Comment: @Lirik Hi, I am a newbie to iOS dev by swift. Could you please give me some hints about how to make sure that I am accessing the getAuthorsCount() after I are getting the result in code?

Comment: @SunsetWan is it working now?

Comment: @SunsetWan the line you added is exactly the answer. The other getAuthorsCount() and the print() statements are not relevant.

Comment: @SunsetWan I edited my answer for you to understand everything you are doing. Hope this helps and you can validate the answer. You may want to ask another question about how to use the data you saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer all your questions :

- The data is persistant
- You are doing the following : Alamo.request (Network call) -> getAuthors(print result - empty) ->
  response (receive response) -> self.authors.append(save response) -> self.authors (print result)
- You need to do : Alamo.request (Network call) -> response (receive response) -> self.authors.append(save response) -> self.getAuthors or getAuthors(same) (inside the response {})

You need to call getAuthors once you have your result, inside the response callback :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
                    for item in json["books"].arrayValue {
                        var outputString: String
                        print(item["author"])
                        outputString = item["author"].stringValue
                        //urlOfProjectAsset.append(outputString)
                        self.authors.append(outputString)
                        print("authors.count: \(self.authors.count)")
                    }

                    self.getAuthorsCount()
                    print("-------------")
                   //Do whatever you want from here : present/push 


                }
            }
        }
```

Then you can use the saved data :

- To send the data to another ViewController you can use various methods (present/push, closure/callback, ...)
- Usually you will have a loading spinner to wait for the network to
  answer then you will show your next controller

Comment: But I used func print() to show the content of "var authors = [String]() " , I still got an empty array of string. How can I make the data persistent in "var authors = [String]()"? Because I want to use it  in another view controller.

Comment: Should I use  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) to meet my need ?

Comment: @SunsetWan, I edited my answer to cover all your questions. Hope this helps. This should answer the "how to save the data" question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As requested via direct message: a Swift-only approach. Just paste this in a blank Playground:

```
import Foundation

final class NetworkService {

  enum ServiceError: LocalizedError {
    case invalidUrl
    case networkingError(error: Error)
    case parsingError

    var localizedDescription: String? { return String(describing: self) }
  }


  func request(completion: @escaping (Result<[UserObject], Error>) -> Void ) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else {
      completion(.failure(ServiceError.invalidUrl))
      return
    }

    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (jsonData, response, error) in
      if let jsonData = jsonData {
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
          let users = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserObject].self, from: jsonData)
          completion(.success(users))
        } catch {
          completion(.failure(ServiceError.parsingError))
        }

      } else if let error = error {
        completion(.failure(ServiceError.networkingError(error: error)))
      }
    }
    dataTask.resume()

  }
}

struct UserObject: Codable {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let username: String
  let email: String?
  let website: String?
}


let networkService = NetworkService()
networkService.request { result in

  switch result {
  case .success(let users):
    debugPrint("Received \(users.count) users from REST API")
    debugPrint(users)
  case .failure(let error):
    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
  }

}
```